# Splitting Field of $x^6+2$

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

> Consider the polynomial $g(x) = x^6 + 2$. Compute the degree of the splitting field $M$
> of $g(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I've been struggling with this question now for a bit and I'm not really sure what the answer is. Earlier in the question we calculated the splitting field of $f(x) = x^6 + 3$, which I found to be $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]-3)$, since we can make the sixth root of unity $\zeta = \frac{1 + \sqrt -3}{2}$ out of $\sqrt[6]-3$.

It would then make sense to  me that the splitting field for $g(x)$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]-2,\zeta)$, since $g(x)$ certainly splits in this field. However, the hint for this question is that "*You may assume that the polynomial $x^2 + 3$ has no root in the extension of $\mathbb Q$ generated by $g(x)$*" which invalidates my guess since $\sqrt-3 = 2\zeta-1\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]-2,\zeta)$.

The only other thing I could think of would be if I could somehow be smart with some type of simple extension. However, even if I could find a potential candidate (which I can't using products of $\zeta$ and $\sqrt[6] -2$), using some software I can see the Galois group is of size $12$, which would mean $g(x)$ would have to be a degree $12$ polynomial which clearly isn't true.

Where is the flaw in my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: From what you are saying it looks like you interpreted "in the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $g(x)$" to be the splitting field of $g$. They mean $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(g(x))$, adding one root.

Comment: The phrase "the extension of $\mathbf Q$ generated by $g(x)$" is bad English. There is an "extension of a field generated by a root of a polynomial" if the polynomial is irreducible over that field, and there is an "extension of a field generated by all roots of a polynomial" (i.e., the splitting field of the polynomial over the base field), but there is no such thing as an "extension of a field generated by a polynomial". You deserve to get a better written hint. If this is homework, ask the instructor to clarify the meaning.

Comment: I see... So I assume the hint is saying $x^2 + 3$ has no root over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]-2)$, in which case my guess would be correct, which matches with my computational answer. Thanks!